# Match everything up to a number in a comma delimited list of numbers

Tags: regex, string

I have a comma delimited list of numbers. I need to match everything up to but not including the number I pass in without any trailing comma.

This is an example of a string I'll be searching:

```
1,2,3,5,11,12,13
```

So if I'm looking for "3" I should get "1,2". If I'm looking for "12" I should get "1,2,3,5,11"

Each number will only appear once in the string.

I came up with this which works for everything apart from "1" where it fails for reason I do not fully understand. If I'm looking for "1" there should be no matches. I have looked for solutions but a lot of 'match up to X' questions have a unique part of the string which makes life easier. With numbers one number could be part of another number e.g. "3" and "13".

```
 (.*?)(?=,?[^0-9]5)
```

I know I could do this with a string split and I may well end up doing it that way. However since I started trying and don't get many opportunities to expand my knowledge of regex I'd really like to see a solution for this problem.

*Btw - C# flavoured regex*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think smth like that should work if you want everything before the first occurrence of a number and exactly this number and not some other number that has it as a preffix:

```
^(.*?)(?=(,|^)your-number(,|$))
```

For a specific number it'll look like that:

```
^(.*?)(?=(,|^)12(,|$))
```

For input from your example and number `1` it matches empty string as requested.

Comment: Perfect, I can see exactly what I was missing. So easy when you know how.